# how to fix onOptionsItemSelected when Im converting an activity to a fragment

Tags: android

I'm converting some activities to several fragments , and now when I press back button it doesn't work.

what changes should I do in this fragment when its returning back to Previous activity and when returning to Previous fragment?

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.returnHome:

            Intent i= new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), WoundNavigation.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are adding the fragment in backstack as long as I understand you. Otherwise give some more explanation to help us and yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

write this in onCreateView() method

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

and make these changes

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.returnHome:

            Intent i= new Intent(getActivity(), WoundNavigation.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        case android.R.id.home:
            getActivity().onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

It may help. If this also doesn't  works then you have to manage fragment backstack in activity from where you are calling your fragment

Comment: it works now when I want return from first fragment of current activity to previus activity. what should I do when I want return from second fragment to first fragment of current activity?